# why is it not assigning the string to the label? or how do i get the value out of the array into the label?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsarray, uilabel

I'm trying to assign a label a value from an Array but I don't know why its not working
[image: debug]

im trying to add the value of `cowid` from the array `info` into the label `vaca`, but its not working.

Comment: What happens if you try to print out detalles.Cowid in NSLog right before the label.text assignment?

Comment: it returns 0 before and after

Comment: NSLog detalles, it seems that either it is nil or detalles.Cowid is never set.

Comment: i think its nil, but i dont know why

Comment: You need to look at where DetDiagnostico items are alloc'd and added to the items array.

Comment: DetDiagnostico is an entity, i have it in other parts of the app and it works, or what do you recommend i do?

Comment: If that is the case then there could be a lot of different things happening. I would suggest finding the last place it works fine before the code you mention above. If it works fine there then see what happens between then and where you perform the method above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error and the problem was that i wasn't populating the array before i used it to it was empty. i Solved it by simply putting `DetDiagnostico *detalles = [info objectAtIndex:0];` after `self.info = objects;` this worked just fine!

Answer (score 1):

`cowid` is clearly null here so has not been initialized. `stringWithFormat` shows this with the `(null)`. You can have the confirmation by

```
if (detalles.Cowid == nil) {
    NSLog(@"The Cow has no id");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, what he said.  detalles is nil.

Comment: I did not say detalles is nil. Cowid is nil. This is why in my sample code I check detalles.Cowid.

Comment: is there another way to get cowid form the info array?

Comment: I think I now get what you want. In your code you assign `detalles.Cowid` to `vaca.text`, but you want to assign `info.Cowid` to it.

Comment: Look at the screenshot of the debugger.  detalles is nil.  Why is it nil?  You need to debug your own code to figure that out.

Comment: Thanks nicholas i hadnt noticed that i was looking at info array always, but holy crap there is no need to vote down the question, its a serious doubt i had that i want to solve